CSS imports aren't working from javascript files bundling with Parcel.js
I'm facing an issue regarding importing CSS in .tsx files after upgrading Parcel.js from 2.9.0 to 2.12.0 in a project.
My project is using React, TypeScript and CSS. I'm not using CSS modules. The CSS imports look like this:
// In app.tsx
import "./app.css"

I also have some global imports in my index.html file like this:
<style>
  @import "./vars.css";
  @import "./index.css";
</style>

In version 2.9.0 there were no issues, and the CSS was loading properly.
After upgrading, it seems that only the global imports from index.html are working, and the CSS imported in my .tsx files either are not being loaded or is being transformed in such a way that they are not being applied anymore. When I inspect element (in Chrome) and look at styles for a component, I don't see the styles for components that previously had them (it only shows the global styles).
So far I've tried without success:

Clearing the cache, node_modules, etc. and reinstalling/rebuilding from scratch
Setting cssModules: false explicitly in my package.json
Changing the CSS import syntax

I also put together a toy example to replicate this here: https://github.com/fullthom/parcel-2.12.0-css-imports
I am expecting the CSS in app.css to be included in the result of running parcel index.html but it is not.

In index.html, instead of using an inline <script>:
<script type="module">
  import "./app.tsx";
</script>

Consider referencing app.tsx as an external file as per the example in Parcel's documentation for React:
<script type="module" src="./app.tsx"></script>

